# 警告 -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on ...への対処方法

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS9
iPhone5s

textfieldをタップしてソフトウェアキーボードを起動し、
何かキーをロングプレスして離すと、下記の警告がでます。

2016-02-22 21:01:52.509 KeyboardTest[5568:543794] -[UIWindow　endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on > without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.

警告中にあるメソッドは、リファレンスにも見当たらない。
回転やキーボードに関係するところも調べましたが、原因や対処方がわかりませんでした。
警告だけなので無視してもいいものなのか、どなたか知見をお持ちの方がいればご教授おねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

私もkeyboarddismissmodeプロパティを設定すると同じような警告文がでました。
私の場合シミュレータ上では警告文が出ましたが、実機では出ませんでしたので無視しても良いかと思います。
実機でも同様の警告文が出ていますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  私の方では実機でも警告でますね。  でも今のところ支障は確認できないので無視してます。(^^)